# SQLite Record Format two or three byte varints how to reach the BLOB LIMIT 231-1 or 2147483647

Tags: sqlite

I'm reading SQLite doc, but have some confused
[SQLite File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)

> The header size varint and serial type varints will usually consist of a single byte. The serial type varints for large strings and BLOBs might extend to two or three byte varints, but that is the exception rather than the rule. The varint format is very efficient at coding the record header.

The doc says the serial type varints no more than three byte, but the blob type limit size is 2147483647, [SQLite limits](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: Sane people aren't going to be storing multi gigabyte blobs and strings in a database?

Comment: @Shawn The SQLite doc say in header size they use no more than 3 byte to calculate the content length(such as blob or string content), but three byte = 2^25 -1 less than the limit size of the blob is = 2^31- 1